# Regex to find a value after a specific word with Google App Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I have a string and I wrote following code to extract "NewUsers19" from that.

```js
function getNoOfUsers() {

  var noSpace = "UserRejectedOrderCount25NewUsers19FundedNewUsers14DepositAmount($)43165.23DepositCount75WithdrawAmount($)53510";
  var regex = /(?:NewUsers)([0-9]+)/;
  var value = regex.exec(noSpace);
  return value;
  
}
```

The regex worked fine in online editors but I don't know why it does not work in Google App Script. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need `19` or  the whole `NewUsers19`? Note that you ran a regex against `noSpace`, but `string` contains the expected match.

Comment: Yes I need 19. Even I get NewUsers19 its fine

Comment: Ok, I think it is related to GAS, you must remove the non-capturing group and then print `value[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the non-capturing group and then return `value[1]`:

```
function getNoOfUsers() {
  var noSpace = "UserRejectedOrderCount25NewUsers19FundedNewUsers14DepositAmount($)43165.23DepositCount75WithdrawAmount($)53510";
  var regex = /NewUsers([0-9]+)/;
  var value = regex.exec(noSpace);
  return value ? value[1] : "";
}
```

Tested in Google Docs:

[image]